# Convert Parameter Value Form DateTime To Int32

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I am having problems with a Stored Procedure I am writing.

I am gathering data from a number of tables, most of which hold a date value, but one holds just a month(int)

I declare the following Parameters at the beginning of my SP.

```
@FromDate DateTime,
@ToDate DateTime
```

This works fine for most of my tables, but for the table where I am just requiring the Month from the @FromDate, I run into the following error:

> "Failed to convert parameter value form a DateTime to a Int32."

Here is my Select statement for the Problem Table:

```
SELECT Branch, Discount 
    FROM MonthlyPromotions
    WHERE (Month = DATEPART(mm,@FromDate))
```

Also, in the MonthlyPromotions Table the Month Field is an Int.

Can anyone help on this ASAP??

Thankyou

Comment: MONTH is a reserved keyword, try aliasing your table and then reference the Month column (alias.Month).

Comment: Or you can just use `[Month]` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot your problem, can you do a

```
PRINT CAST(CAST(DATEPART(mm, @FromDate) AS INT) AS VARCHAR(50))
RETURN
```

At the beginning of your SP?
If that doesn't give an error, you can proceed to:

```
SELECT Branch, Discount 
    FROM MonthlyPromotions
    WHERE Month = CAST(DATEPART(mm,@FromDate) AS INT)
```

Comment: Well, today I heard that sometimes you need to pray to Prequel, the god of SQL who created all scripts and syntax. That's probably the real answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(getdate() as int)
```